# Changing the value of the buttons to Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function

I have this code on my page to change the content of my `<iframe>` with two buttons

- Previous
- Next

it only works if I have the value of the buttons set to previous and next and I would like to add functions names to do the same than the buttons and so change the name of the buttons to Before and After.

--- What I want to get are basically two functions one that makes the same than previous and one for next ---

Here is the code

```
<input type="button" value="Previous" />
<input type="button" value="Next" />
<br />
<iframe id="frame" src="1.html">
</iframe>

<script>
    var locations = ["1.html", "2.html", "3.html","4.html"];
    var currentIndex = 0;
    var len = locations.length;

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(':button').click(function() {
             currentIndex = this.value == "Next" ? 
             currentIndex < len - 1 ? ++currentIndex : 0 : 
             currentIndex > 0 ? --currentIndex : len - 1;
             $('#frame').attr('src', locations[currentIndex]);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well, you want something like

```
var locations = ["1.html", "2.html", "3.html","4.html"],
    len = locations.length;
var currentIndex = (function(){
    var index = 0;
    return function(idx) {
        if(idx === void(0)) return index;
        index = idx;
        $('#frame').attr('src', locations[index]);
    }
})();
/* To read currentIndex use `currentIndex()`
   To set currentIndex use `currentIndex(value)` */
function prev() {
    currentIndex(currentIndex() < len - 1 ? currentIndex()+1 : 0);
}
function next() {
    currentIndex(currentIndex() > 0 ? currentIndex()-1 : len - 1);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#prev')
        .val('Previous')
        .click(prev);
    $('#next')
        .val('Next')
        .click(next);
});

<input type="button" id="prev" />&nbsp;<input type="button" id="next" />
<br />
<iframe id="frame" src="1.html">
</iframe>
```

Comment: They modified my question so now is more confusing but what I basically want are two functions: One to make the same than the next button and the other to make the same than the previous button, because now I can only make the buttons work if I have their values set to previous or next.

Comment: oh wait... you missed the iframe

Answer (score 0):

Oriol's answer gives you two functions. I would go about it like this:

> var locations = ["1.html", "2.html", "3.html","4.html"],

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        var locations = ["1.html", "2.html", "3.html","4.html"];
      var currentIndex = 0;
      var len = locations.length;
      function  prev() {
        if(currentIndex == 0){ 
        currentIndex = len-1;
        }else{
        currentIndex--;
        }
        $('#frame').attr('src', locations[currentIndex]);

        }
     function next() {
        if(currentIndex == len -1){ 
        currentIndex = 0;
        }else{
        currentIndex++;
        }
        $('#frame').attr('src', locations[currentIndex]);
        }
      $('#prev').click(prev);

        $('#next').click(next);
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type = "button" id = "prev" value = "Before" />&nbsp;<input type = "button" value = "After" id = "next" />
    <br />
    <iframe id="frame" src="1.html"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: well yes I tried this before but do you see a way to make two functions out of this  -- one function for the next and the other for the previous since using functions could give me more flexibility with the design that I am making - thanks

Comment: thats an update that implements two functions, just like Oriol's answer

Comment: Could you put it on the code because for some reason for me it's not working I don't know if I am putting in the wrong place but I don't think so. [here is the code](http://pastebin.com/esbmBUWV) I really appreciate thanks a lot.

Comment: i just did, but someone got to review it and then you are going to be able too see it. I tested it and it works though

Comment: Asker explicitly said "*I would like to add functions names to do the same than the buttons*". But your functions are anonymous, so they don't have any name thought they can be called.